# Distribution of a continuous random variable

Tags: probability

I was reading through my"Random Variability in Business Situations" notes and wanted to enquire about some difficulty I've encountered.

On the fourth and final column "probability calculated from model X~N (53, 2^2)" how are the values determined? What steps are taken? Because from "X is greater then/equal to 47 and less than 48" there is a 0.0003 difference between the last two columns (0.0048 and 0.0045). I am very interested to understand why this is happening.

The mean weight is 53g and the standard deviation is 2g. Please refer to the image below for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the third column is simply the number f/5000, where f is the number given in the second column.

In the fourth column, we assume X is normally distributed with mean 53 and standard deviation 2.  If you want to use a standard normal table to look up the probability of, say, $47\leq X < 48$, you would "normalize" the variable, by subtracting off the mean and dividing by the standard deviation.  That is,

$$P(47\leq X < 48) = P\left(\frac{47-53}{2}\leq \frac{X-53}{2} < \frac{48-53}{2}\right) = P\left(-3\leq \frac{X-53}{2} < -\frac{5}{2}\right)$$

Now, the variable $Z = \frac{X-53}{2}$ is a standard normal random variable, so you can use the standard normal table to look up this probability, or you can use Wolfram alpha.

Go to [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) and type in the phrase

"probability standard normal between -3 and -5/2"

You will see that it is equal to 0.004859.  However, this doesn't explain why they have put 0.0045 in the last column.  I suspect they used normal tables to get an approximation, and the number given by Wolfram alpha is more accurate than theirs.  As long as you understand what I've described above, I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm french, so it could explain my bad english.
The probability density function is known by the mean and the variance :

$p(x)\ =\ \tfrac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}\ \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2}$

The probability that $X$ is greater then/equal to $47$ and less than $48$ is the integral of the density function between these bounds.